# Как сделать поле город изначально пустое

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Сайт вп+вукомерс+плагин доставки сдек. На странице оформления заказа -->
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать "Москва". Как я понял там стоит select2. Потому что в инспекторе `<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-billing_city-container" title="Москва">Москва</span>`

Т.е смысл в том чтобы поле город было изначально пустое.

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в список 
    `<option value='0' selected default >Не выбран</option>` 
и по умолчанию он должен первым встать